# SPO Modern Site - Hide the Suite Bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, script-webpart, suitebar

I have a requirement to hide the O365 - SharePoint suite bar / ribbon  on modern communication site and on the site pages, but there do not seems to be an OOTB setting / option to do so (yet).

We used a script editor webpart on the landing page of a communication site and altered the visibility of the suite / ribbon using CSS, with this we are experiencing a minimum of 2-3 secs delay in getting rid of the ribbon before the page is rendered. Now, if we want to completely get rid of the ribbon, we would have to add the script editor on every site page that are already there and any site page that may be needed in the future, this solution proves to be a redundant and cumbersome

Though it’s not recommend to remove O365 Bar, would like to know if there are any other alternatives for this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Script Editor, You can create the SPFx Extenstion, [Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension).

Do not put any UI related code in the render method and just add the code of hiding the Suite Bar using CSS or JavaScript whatever approach you want to use.

Deploy the Extension on Site level and it will hide the suit bar on all the pages. Including Existing and New.